# Django Channels send to group from view

Tags: django, django-channels

i am trying to send a message to a group from outside the consumer "from view ..."

documentation saying `async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("chat", {"type": "message_handler"})` but what i don't get is how to define the `message_handler` in the view because i am getting this error

> No handler for message type message_handler

Comment: `channel_layer.group_send` with `"type": "message_handler"` will invoke the `message_handler` method of your consumer. The error says your consumer does not define this method. Views cannot receive channel messages, only consumers can. Where you send the message _from_ is irrelevant.

Comment: but in this case i am not receiving anything i am trying to send

Comment: There is an error, you are not supposed to receive anything if your program stops working.

Comment: sir please read carefully, i am trying to SEND a message to a group from views.py and not consumers.py, that's all.

Comment: As I said, it does not matter where you send it from. You can send it from views.py. But a consumer will have to receive it — and you haven't written the code for that.

Comment: can you please give me a simple example on how to do so?

Comment: Define `async def message_handler(self, event):` inside the consumer whose channel you are sending to.

Comment: already did that in "consumers.py" but i am working under "views.py" environment so i don't have access to that handler, maybe i have to redefine that in views.py somehow

Comment: For the last time, where you send the message from _does not matter_. What is this talk about environments? Django Channels will route your message to any consumers that have joined the group `"chat"`. There is no "access" that you need to have. If you already have defined `message_handler` method there, then you should not be receiving the error you reported. It may be clearer if you posted the relevant code of your consumer.

Comment: Also, it would be useless to define such a method outside a consumer, because Channels delivers messages to consumers, and consumers only.

Comment: oh i defined the handler in a consumer and added the channel to the group from another, working now, thank you so much sir!